# nodejs with mongoose adding numbers

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My model:

```
var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...
...
...
, sortId: Number
...
})
```

my code:

```
var ca = 0
Category.findOne({orgId: user.orgId}).desc('sortId').run(function(err, cat){
 if(cat != null){
  ca = cat.sortId + 1
 }
})
console.log(ca)
```

"ca" keep being 0, even though that it find a record where sortId is 1. Any who can see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner function is async, the console log is being called prior to the function being run to completion.